# How to only sum certain properties in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have dynamic object properties that collectively equal the score in the same object. What would be the best way to sum only those types of values together to write to that score property?

```
0: Object
id: 1
name: "Player 1"
score: 0
1game1: 10

1: Object
id: 2
name: "Player 2"
score: 0
2game1: 10
2game2: 15
```

Ideally, the result would be:

```
0: Object
id: 1
name: "Player 1"
score: 10
1game1: 10

1: Object
id: 2
name: "Player 2"
score: 25
2game1: 10
2game2: 15
```

This is being used in React as a state to update the score based on values for each "game". So there could be more games added or removed and the scores can be edited at any time.

Comment: Have you considered modifying the data structure, e.g. by replacing the `2game1/2` properties with an array `games: [10, 15]`?

Comment: @A_A yes. I have. But if the values change then I'd need a way to update that change. I am not sure I can do that in a single dimension array without looping back through all the values. I'd rather just try and handle one value at a time and then zero out the score and calculate based on what that one player has score-wise.

Answer (score 2):

Just like the comment, generally I would also suggest switching to arrays, even at the expense of nesting them (for tracking the parts of a single game).

Technically what you can do now is looping over the object fields and summing them whenever their name contains "game" in it:

```js
function setScore(o) {
  return o.score = Object.keys(o).reduce(
    (sum, key) => key.indexOf("game") !== -1 ? sum + o[key] : sum, 0);
}
let o1 = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Player 1",
  score: 0,
  "1game1": 10
};
let o2 = {
  id: 2,
  name: "Player 2",
  score: 0,
  "2game1": 10,
  "2game2": 15
}
console.log(setScore(o1));
console.log(o1);
console.log(setScore(o2));
console.log(o2);
```

Comment: One might even think about to narrow the key check to [`key.startsWith(o.id + 'game')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).

Comment: @PeterSeliger I don't pretend I understand the naming convention. You may be right about the `id`, but  I don't know.

Comment: Thats why I was formulating it very vaguely. It was a safety concern raised as reminder also mainly to the OP. And before I commented I gave you the upvote anyhow.